# embedded video in iframe freezing the browser

Tags: iframe, razor

I am displaying videos in my view this way

```
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://myUrlHere" width="340" height="220">
</iframe>
```

the problem is that when there some long videos in the list, my browser is freezing for a certain period of time.

I tried this with IE8 and firefox and both give the same result.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be weird but I fixed this issue by changing the width of the iframe and now it works just fine